# need sample data for e-commerce master research

Tags: dataset, e-commerce, sample-data

In my MSC research, I have to build an eCommerce app (like Amazon, eBay, etc) but a location based one . I need a freely available sample data for the store. So is there some freely available dataset available that represents a set of products, like groceries, movies, books, cars, apps, electronics, weapons, library, etc? .I need its size to be adequate for analysis. I need a database with at least 200 customers , 1000 products of different categories and 1000 orders. The customers data have to include information such as age, sex, location, education.

Comment: I'd say that part of building and testing any ecommerce app would require a dataset built from generated data (you shouldn't continually test using real data for several reasons), so I'd suggest generating it yourself.

Comment: This question would be on-topic at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Microsoft Contoso BI Demo Dataset](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=868662dc-187a-4a85-b611-b7df7dc909fc).  I have not used it, so I do not know if it will meet all of your requirements.  However, given that it is used to demonstrate BI functionality across all of MS' BI products, one would *hope* it was fairly comprehensive.